# Using $or in a FindOne query - MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**UPDATE:** Changed if (!result.length) to if (!result) as I'm using .findOne and that seems to be working so far. If you spot anything else that can be improved within the code snippet that would be awesome!

Just starting to learn Node JS and MongoDB (using Mongoose) so excuse me if I'm totally out of context.

Im trying to find a row in my MongoDB with the following query:

```
exports.findById = function(req, res) {
        var id = req.params.id;
        Team.findOne({'teamid':id, $or:[{'creator':req.user.id}, {userlist: { $in : [req.user.id]}}]}, function(err, result) {
            if (err) console.log(err);
            if (!result.length)
                res.redirect('/');
            else
                res.render('team', { team : result.teamid });
        });
};
```

I want to retrieve a row that has the field `teamid` equal to `id` as well as to check if the field `creator` is equal to `req.user.id` OR if `req.user.id` is in the `userlist` field. I am expecting only one result from the above query.

Note that this query works just fine, but I just need to look inside the `userlist` array:

```
Team.findOne({'teamid':id, 'creator':req.user.id}, function(err, result) {...
```

And finally the Team schema

```
var Team = new Schema({
        team_name: { type: String, required: true, trim: true},
        teamid: { type: String },
        creator: String,
        created_at: Date,
        userlist: Array
});
```

Any help to figure out what's the problem is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Found a solution, updated question.

Comment: Could you add your solution as an answer to the question? This should help any subsequent visitors to this question's page.